# Mapping Gorm queries to lists of structs

Tags: go, orm, go-gorm

Go here, using gorm to help me with database stuff.

I have the following function which is working for me:

```
func (d DbPersister) FetchOrderById(orderId string) (Order,error) {
  order := &Order{}

  if err := d.GormDB.Table("orders").
        Select(`orders`.`order_id`,
              `orders`.`quantity`,
              `addresses`.`line_1`,
              `addresses`.`state`,
              `addresses`.`zip`).
        Joins("join addresses on addresses.address_id = orders._address_id").
        Where("orders.order_id = ?", orderId).
        First(order).Error; err != nil {
        return Order{}, err
    }

  return *order,nil
}
```

So, you give it an `orderId`, and it fetches that from the DB and maps it to an `Order` instance.

I now want to look up all a particular user's orders:

```
func (d DbPersister) FetchAllOrdersByCustomerId(userId string) ([]Order,error) {
  orders := []&Order{}
  
  if err := d.GormDB.Table("orders").
        Select(`orders`.`order_id`,
            `orders`.`quantity`,
            `orders`.`status`,
            `addresses`.`line_1`,
            `addresses`.`state`,
            `addresses`.`zip`).
        Joins("join addresses on addresses.address_id = orders.shipping_address_id").
        Joins("join users on users.user_id = orders.user_id").
        Where("users.user_id = ?", userId).
        First(orders).Error; err != nil {
        return []Order{}, err
    }

  return orders,nil
}
```

However, I'm getting compiler errors. I don't believe `First(orders)` is the correct function to be calling here. Basically do a join between orders and users and give me all of a particular user's orders, which should be a list of `Order` instances. Can anyone spot where I'm going awry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly `orders := []&Order{}` should be `orders := make([]Order,0)`

Then use `Find()` instead of `First()` to get multiple values.

For structs, slices, maps, and other composite types, if no data is contained you can return **nil**

So your code should be

```golang
func (d DbPersister) FetchAllOrdersByCustomerId(userId string) ([]Order,error) {
  orders := make([]Order,0)
  
   if err := d.GormDB.Table("orders").
        Select(`orders`.`order_id`,
            `orders`.`quantity`,
            `orders`.`status`,
            `addresses`.`line_1`,
            `addresses`.`state`,
            `addresses`.`zip`).
        Joins("join addresses on addresses.address_id = orders.shipping_address_id").
        Joins("join users on users.user_id = orders.user_id").
        Where("users.user_id = ?", userId).
        Find(&orders).Error; err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

  return orders,nil
}
```